# Chrome DevTools Protocol: How to get click event handler name of a Node

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

**Problem**

I have a list of the same nodes that has the same handler or function attached to it.

I need to click each and every interactive node present in the DOM (this is the functionality or requirement).

**I would like to skip the Node to be clicked if they are already clicked or if the Node has the same handler attached to it.**

Please find below the screenshot for the reference. In which the event listener has a click event with the handler name attached to it. Can we get the name of the click handler or function?

I am using `DOMDebugger.getEventListeners({ objectId: remoteObjectId })` but it will not returning the `handler and originalHandler` don't why.

[image]

Comment: Apparently it's a "framework" listener which is attached to `document` or `window` and then uses *event delegation* (based on element selector or whatever) to route to your actual listener. To get all listeners you can specify `depth` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quirk mentioned [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3349#issuecomment-548428762): you need `objectGroup` set to get the handler. Here are some ways to get the name:

```js
const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8'>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script>
        function main() {
          document.body.addEventListener('click', logClick);
        }

        function logClick() {
          console.log('click');
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='main();'>Text.</body>
  </html>`;

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();

    const nodeObject = (await cdp.send('Runtime.evaluate', {
      expression: "document.querySelector('body')",
      objectGroup: 'foobar',
    })).result;

    const listenerObject = (await cdp.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', {
      objectId: nodeObject.objectId,
    })).listeners[0].handler;

    const listenerName1 = (await cdp.send('Runtime.callFunctionOn', {
      functionDeclaration: 'function() { return this.name; }',
      objectId: listenerObject.objectId,
      returnByValue: true,
    })).result.value;

    const listenerName2 = (await cdp.send('Runtime.getProperties', {
      objectId: listenerObject.objectId,
      ownProperties: true,
    })).result.find(property => property.name === 'name').value.value;

    await cdp.send('Runtime.releaseObject', { objectId: listenerObject.objectId });
    await cdp.send('Runtime.releaseObject', { objectId: nodeObject.objectId });
    await cdp.send('Runtime.releaseObjectGroup', { objectGroup: 'foobar' });

    console.log(listenerName1);
    console.log(listenerName2);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Output:

```
logClick
logClick
```

---

**UPD**
Anonymous handlers:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/inline.html');

    const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();

    const nodeObject = (await cdp.send('Runtime.evaluate', {
      expression: "document.querySelector('a.ui-datepicker-next')",
      objectGroup: 'foobar',
    })).result;

    const listenerObject = (await cdp.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', {
      objectId: nodeObject.objectId,
    })).listeners[0].handler;

    console.log(listenerObject);

    await cdp.send('Runtime.releaseObject', { objectId: listenerObject.objectId });
    await cdp.send('Runtime.releaseObject', { objectId: nodeObject.objectId });
    await cdp.send('Runtime.releaseObjectGroup', { objectGroup: 'foobar' });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

output:

```js
{
  type: 'function',
  className: 'Function',
  description: 'function( e ) {\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t// Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t// when an event is called after a page has unloaded\n' +
    '\t\t\t\treturn typeof jQuery !== "undefined" &&\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t\t( !e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ) ?\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t\tjQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t\tundefined;\n' +
    '\t\t\t}',
  objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":3,"id":2}'
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vsemozhebuty **objectGroup** is the most important key.

Comment: The above code does not work for the https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/inline.html. Here i am tring to get expression: "document.querySelector('a.ui-datepicker-next')", next and previous buttons of the calendar. Does above code only work for SPA?

Comment: @PradeepGill Maybe there are some anonymous functions among the handlers. See an example with your code at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if the elemenets are statics and not dynamic in your website I advise you a solution.
because this elements have a common selector you can you use this.page.$$ and get the array of all them. After that create a object with {button: elementHandle, isClicked: } and this way you could know if the node is clicked or not.
I wish that this solution will help you.

page.$$ - https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageselector-1

remark: if to selector have more event or something changed you could know if it clicked. for example the color.