# getEventListeners is not defined in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

When I try to use `getEventListeners` in puppeteerSharp I got `getEventListeners is not defined` error:

```
var result = await page.EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync("getEventListeners(document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0])");
```

How to use `getEventListeners` within puppeteerSharp?

I found this for javascript:

```
const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();    
const listeners = await cdp.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', { objectId });
```

and I tried to convert it back into C#:

```
var t = await page.EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync(@"document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0]");
var client = await page.Target.CreateCDPSessionAsync();
var result = await client.SendAsync("DOMDebugger.getEventListeners", t.RemoteObject.ObjectId);
```

but it seems I'm doing something wrong and I did not find any clear documentation about this.

Comment: getEventListeners is a console utility that is not an available function to use in a script https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#geteventlisteners

Comment: @hardkoded ok, But how to use it within puppeteer?

Comment: @hardkoded here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059096/chrome-devtools-protocol-how-to-get-click-event-handler-name-of-a-node in the first answer, it seems he uses `getEventListeners`. but I do not know how to convert it back into c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, here it is for those who may be interested:

First, we should create a `CDPSession` like this:

```
var client = await page.Target.CreateCDPSessionAsync();
```

then we should Evaluate our script to get an element:

```
var body = await client.SendAsync("Runtime.evaluate", new { expression = "document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]" });
```

and at last, we should use `DOMDebugger` with the element's `objectId` to get its `event listeners`:

```
var result = await client.SendAsync("DOMDebugger.getEventListeners", new { objectId = body["result"]["objectId"] });
```